# can i encrypt downloaded files in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to write a chrome extension to encrypt downloaded files? I also need to insert a header to encrypted file which makes file larger than original one.

Comment: Use the standard JS methods, there's no special encryption API for extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If you wan't to use one that already exists use this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fluffypuffin-file-encrypt/klbknjbjhpikjddjfbmlmmpnhngonljp?hl=en-GB

Comment: great, thank you very much. One thing i notice is, this extension downloads files to disk first then encrypts and deletes it. Is it possbile to encrypt file on the fly without saving original file to disk to avoid potential data leak?

Comment: I think so, if you wan't to do that you might want to look at the source code and change it a bit.